# android app development compatible to multiple screen sizes

Tags: android

consider a requirement of an app which need to be run on different screen sizes. lets say app has text fields ediboxes list view etc... and in each screen size the width/height of each ui component has to vary. how to desing an UI for this kind of requirement. please suggest.

Comment: is the page of google blocked on ur system?..google it..there is a great documentation on [developers.android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) site...

Comment: The Android UI system is designed to address this very problem with layout components like LinearLayout, RelativeLayout etc. Review Googles documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Answer (score 1):

Use Width and Height as fill_Parent or wrap_content..
if you are using images make different sizes images and put it in drawable-hdpi,drawable-ldpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi.The Sizes for those imagaes are in developer.android.com

Answer (score 0):

In the res folder,there exists folder named layout,that the default folder which the system find the layout defination.But people also can make other folder like

- layout-480x800
- layout-1024x768

and so on ,and put the layout files in it.
When the app run on a device which have the certain size,the app will auto find the layout defination in the same folder,if cant it will use the default defination.